# Pandas - fill new column with values from following day

Tags: python, pandas

In the following dataframe

```
#Create data
data = {'Day': [1,1,2,2,3,3],
        'Where': ['A','B','A','B','B','B'],
        'What': ['x','y','x','x','x','y'],
        'Dollars': [100,200,100,100,100,200]}

index = range(len(data['Day']))

columns = ['Day','Where','What','Dollars']


df = pd.DataFrame(data,  index=index, columns=columns)
df
```

[image: fff]

I would like to add a column with the future values. In this case, the first value should be 100 as on day 2 at A x was sold for 100 dollars. The complete column should contain the values `100, None, None, 100, None, None`.

I thought that I could index the cells in the following way

```
df2 = df
df2['Tomorrow_Dollars'] = df[df.Day == df2.Day+1,'Dollars']
```

but this throws the following error

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Is there a solution to this or a smarter approach?

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: @coldspeed please, notice that I did: a column with 100, None, None, 100, None, None. Sorry, if it is a bit hidden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea is add create missing combinations by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for unique `Days`, so possible `shift`. Last reshape back and `join` for new column:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Day','Where','What'])
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels, names=df1.index.names)

s = df1.reindex(mux)['Dollars'].unstack([1,2]).shift(-1).unstack().rename('Tomorrow_Dollars')

df = df.join(s, on=['Where','What','Day'])
print (df)
   Day Where What  Dollars  Tomorrow_Dollars
0    1     A    x      100             100.0
1    1     B    y      200               NaN
2    2     A    x      100               NaN
3    2     B    x      100             100.0
4    3     B    x      100               NaN
5    3     B    y      200               NaN
```

Comment: :O I could have never done that! Thank you! Could you please briefly explain to me also the reason for the error I got?

Comment: @shamalaia - Sure, error correct is simple - `df.loc[df.Day == df2.Day+1,'Dollars']` - it is chained [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with selecting column `Dollars`. Unfortunately some values are missing, so need reindex like in my answer.